# Resizing app iframe to get rid of all scrollbars in firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps

I have made an app which will be a FB page tab. Now I am trying to get rid of the scrollbars that come when the content exceeds 800px height. I used the following code to do this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId : '<?php echo $app_id; ?>',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml : true // parse XFBML
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    }
    // Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
    function sizeChangeCallback() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize(); 
    }
</script>
```

Now this works fine for Google Chrome but shows scrollbars for firefox. In fact, initially there was no horizontal scrollbar which has now appeared. At some blog it was written that to get rid of this error we should set overflow to hidden. I tried doing that too but that cuts of the content. What is the solution to this? This is my CSS for html and body:

```
html {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    min-height: 798px;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    width: 495px;
    overflow: hidden;
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
color: #444444;
font-family: lucida grande, tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been having the same issue with firefox adding scrollbars to my facebook page/tab.
The fix in the end was...

1. In the app setting make sure you have 'page tab' and 'app on facebook' set up with the page tab/canvas url and the secure version.
2. The code:

> 

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'FB_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'FB_CHANNEL_URL', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Good luck!

Comment: this worked perfectly for me, didn't need channelUrl though - never even heard of it before!

Comment: channelUrl is optional but good to resolve certain problems like cross-browser communication. I don't use it unless I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Make one function as follows:

```
function grow()
  {

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();

     }
```

Call this function on body onload event as `<body onLoad="grow()">`

Hope it works,cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue as well and after some hours of reading posts on the web I finally found a solution that works. Provided you have included this div in your markup:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Just add this script at the end of your file (before closing the body tag):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId:'APP ID',
        status:true,
        cookie:true,
        xfbml:true
    });
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
};

(function (d, debug) {
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, /*debug*/ false));
```

My issue was that depite working on Chrome, Safari and even IE, it still failed in Firefox and Opera. The problem was that the code above was written inside of a **$(document).ready()** function, so Firefox and Opera never fired the **fbAsyncInit** function. After moving the code outside, independent of other functions, everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For me it often helped to set only overflow-x to hidden. That shouldn't cut off content while helping against some quirks in Firefox's size calculations.

EDIT:
The problem is with the order of execution. The Facebook-SDK is executed first. It checks for the existence of window.fbAsyncInit - which is not defined at that point. Later fbAsyncInit is defined but Facebook never checks again so the function isn't executed ever. So setAutoGrow is not executed and the whole magic doesn't happen. Moving the definition of fbAsyncInit to some point before the FB SDK is included should solve the problem.

Comment: with overflow-x: hidden the horizontal scroll bar disappears but the vertical scrollbar still remains. How to get rid of it?

Comment: if the vertical scrollbar doesn't disappear - are you sure setAutoGrow works correctly? That's hard to debug without having access to the frontend (Javascript error-console etc.). Have you tried narrowing it down? Like, for example, make a test-page where the body only contains a div with height: 900px etc.?

Comment: seems like this AutoGrow function is not working...i tried increasing the hieght...the canvas size remains the same...extra content is only visible through scroll bars

Comment: Does the setAutoGrow-line gets executed (break point in firebug)? Are there any warnings/errors in the console?

Comment: in firefox these functions are not entered? the debugger is never reacehd in the function? Any idea why is that?

Comment: Well, if fbAsyncInit is called somewhere in all.js then it's pretty unfortunate. As in: The function isn't defined yet. Maybe that's the reason? P.S.: You shouldn't mix async and sync style. That's a huge bug-producer.

Comment: this is the line in all.js with fbAsyncInit:

Comment: if(window.fbAsyncInit&&!window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun)  {window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun=true;fbAsyncInit();}},0);

Comment: Okay, to elaborate the thing about "async vs. sync". fbAsyncInit is used when you are loading the Facebook SDK asynchronously. <script src="..."> loads a script file synchronously. Mixing both is evil because normally (synchronously) code is executed in the order of appearance in the file. Solution: Either move the code inside fbAsyncInit right after FB.init (without using fbAsyncInit at all) or define fbAsyncInit BEFORE including the FB SDK.

Comment: that seems fine but then there is the problem that the height of the longest page is retained for all the page. Ideally I want, that if the content is more than 800px it should autogrow to accomodate that and if it is less than that the height of the canvas should be 800px

Comment: that's not how "setAutoGrow" works. Facebook even renamed the method to make it more clear: setAutoGrow will only grow the page, never shrink it. but there's always setSize for your shrinking needs - even though you may have to calculate the height by yourself.

Comment: you get the height of the content (using jQuery for example) and then you call FB.Canas.setSize(newSize). Or what is the question?